# Image classification of more than 60,000 classes

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am working on a problem that requires the classification of more than 60k classes. I have around 1k to 1.5k images per class. I am using synthetic data for training and want to evaluate it on real data. I have enough computing power but want to keep it computationally efficient and highly accurate (the tradeoff can be further adjusted).

Currently, I am looking for papers in this direction. All papers mostly work with ImageNet 1k. I have a few things in my mind. I am considering starting with EfficientNet for supervised learning. I am also looking into Hierarchical classification and similarity matching by generating embeddings in multidimensional space.

The data does not have a hierarchy. But I am also looking into it if I could somehow use it in hierarchies.

I want suggestions on this. What methodology is best for it? or if there are any good papers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at CLIP, it's somewhat relevant. The model can is capable of classifying a non-fixed number of classes

Comment: I thought so as well. If you use an embedding model you can always use kNN for classification

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of classes that can be very similar (or not), you could maybe take a look at margin losses such as Arcface of Cosface.

Also start from a very well pretrained foundation model such as DINOv2 and fit a small classifier (even a simple linear layer could work decently) on top of its features.